# SELECT Query merge / join two tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-outer-join

If there are two tables as mentioned below:

**Table 1**

```
    day          acount
    1998-03-01     8
    1998-03-04     9
    1998-03-05     10
    1998-03-09     8
```

**Table 2**

```
    day          bcount
    1998-03-02     9
    1998-03-03     7
    1998-03-05     4
    1998-03-06     3
```

Can a select query return the data in ascending order in the format below?

**Result**

```
    day          acount        bcount
    1998-03-01     8             0
    1998-03-02     0             9
    1998-03-03     0             7
    1998-03-04     9             0
    1998-03-05     10            4
    1998-03-06     3             0
    1998-03-09     8             0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a FULL OUTER JOIN to join the tables on the `day` column to get the result:

```
select coalesce(t1.day, t2.day) "day",
  coalesce(t1.acount, 0) acount,
  coalesce(t2.bcount, 0) bcount
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
  on t1.day = t2.day;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/27ab9/4).  The `COALESCE` function will return the first non-null result, so this can be used to get the `day` values in the same column and then replace the `nulls` in the `acount` and `bcount` columns.

Answer (score 2):

[@bluefeet's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860913/939860) is the way to go. Only adding some syntactical sugar and corrective:

```
SELECT day
     , coalesce(t1.acount, 0) AS acount
     , coalesce(t2.bcount, 0) AS bcount
FROM      table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2 USING (day)
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/27ab9/5)

- If you use the shorter [`USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) for the JOIN condition (possible in this case), you also don't need `coalesce(t1.day, t2.day)`, since this is *exactly* what `day` without table qualification resolves to after being listed in the `USING` clause.
- While it is ok to skip the key word `AS` for table aliases, you should never skip it for column aliases - as documented in the manual in a separate paragraph [*Omitting the `AS` Key Word*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.10.5):

> In `FROM` items, both the standard and PostgreSQL allow `AS` to be omitted
>   before an alias that is an unreserved keyword. But this is impractical
>   for output column names, because of syntactic ambiguities.